# How many times is the IEnumerable ordered in this case?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I know that an `IEnumerable<T>` does not iterate until it is called.

Suppose that I have this code:

```
foreach(int iteratorInt in myIEnumerable.OrderBy(x => x))
{
    if(iteratorInt == myIEnumerable.First())
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

In the `if` I am checking the first element, so does the `myIEnumerable` have to be ordered at each iteration to see which one is the first element or is it ordered just once?

Comment: Just the once, that's how `for` loops work.

Comment: That doesnt compile because `myIEnumerable.OrderBy(x => x.MyProperty)` returns  `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` and not `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks, I have changed to OrderBy(x => x). It was a mistake. Anyway it was a just an example that shows that I am ordering and later checking the first element.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Unless an implicit conversion is created for `SomeClass` and `int`, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: The `OrderBy` is evaluated only once, however, a new `IEnumerator<T>` based on the *original* unordered `myIEnumerable` will be created each iteration, and it will probably *not* match `iteratorInt` on the first iteration.

Comment: You can determine `myIEnumerable.First()` outside the loop and then there are no questions left w.r.t. multiple execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the LINQ extensions, the query will only be executed when requested, otherwise known as deferred execution. When the same query is requested multiple times, the underlying query is re-evaluated each time, unless the initial query has been materialized with something like `.ToArrary()` or `.ToList()`.

The question isn't entirely clear, so I'll provide a few examples demonstrating various behavior.

Ex 1:

- Setting the initial request to a local variable.
- Apply a LINQ query within the foreach to Order the collection.
- Use the initial local variable to find the first result.
- Do not materialize any of the results.

Code:

```
private static void Ex1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("A");

    IEnumerable<int> myIEnumerable = GetEnumerable();

    Console.WriteLine("B");

    foreach (int i in myIEnumerable.OrderBy(x => x))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** foreach : " + i);
        if (i == myIEnumerable.First())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=== Matched .First() : " + i);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("C");
}
```

Ex 2:

- Setting the initial request to a local variable.
- Apply a LINQ query outside the foreach to Order the collection without materializing the result.
- Use the ordered query to find the first result
- Do not materialize any of the results.

Code:

```
private static void Ex2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("A");

    IEnumerable<int> myIEnumerable = GetEnumerable();

    Console.WriteLine("B");

    var ordered = myIEnumerable.OrderBy(x => x);

    foreach (int i in ordered)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** foreach : " + i);
        if (i == ordered.First())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=== Matched .First() : " + i);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("C");
}
```

Ex 3:

- Setting the initial request to a local variable.
- Apply a LINQ query outside the foreach to Order the collection and materialize the result.
- Use the ordered query to find the first result.

Code:

```
private static void Ex3()
{
    Console.WriteLine("A");

    IEnumerable<int> myIEnumerable = GetEnumerable();

    Console.WriteLine("B");

    var ordered = myIEnumerable.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

    foreach (int i in ordered)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** foreach : " + i);
        if (i == ordered.First())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=== Matched .First() : " + i);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("C");
}
```

All queries use the same method to get the enumerable:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetEnumerable()
{
    Console.WriteLine("~~~ GetEnumerable Start");
    foreach (int i in new[]{3, 2, 1})
    {
        Console.WriteLine(">>> yield return : " + i);
        yield return i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("~~~ GetEnumerable End");
}
```

The results will end up as:

```
====================
Ex A
====================
A
B
~~~ GetEnumerable Start
>>> yield return : 3
>>> yield return : 2
>>> yield return : 1
~~~ GetEnumerable End
*** foreach : 1
~~~ GetEnumerable Start
>>> yield return : 3
*** foreach : 2
~~~ GetEnumerable Start
>>> yield return : 3
*** foreach : 3
~~~ GetEnumerable Start
>>> yield return : 3
=== Matched .First() : 3
C

====================
Ex B
====================

A
B
~~~ GetEnumerable Start
>>> yield return : 3
>>> yield return : 2
>>> yield return : 1
~~~ GetEnumerable End
*** foreach : 1
~~~ GetEnumerable Start
>>> yield return : 3
>>> yield return : 2
>>> yield return : 1
~~~ GetEnumerable End
=== Matched .First() : 1
*** foreach : 2
~~~ GetEnumerable Start
>>> yield return : 3
>>> yield return : 2
>>> yield return : 1
~~~ GetEnumerable End
*** foreach : 3
~~~ GetEnumerable Start
>>> yield return : 3
>>> yield return : 2
>>> yield return : 1
~~~ GetEnumerable End
C

====================
Ex C
====================

A
B
~~~ GetEnumerable Start
>>> yield return : 3
>>> yield return : 2
>>> yield return : 1
~~~ GetEnumerable End
*** foreach : 1
=== Matched .First() : 1
*** foreach : 2
*** foreach : 3
C
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Enumerable will be **ordered**  only once, here: `myIEnumerable.OrderBy(x => x)`
At this line `if(iteratorInt == myIEnumerable.First())` it will not be ordered again.

Maybe you misunderstood the `IEnumerable.First` method, there are no relation between `IEnumerable.First` and `IEnumerable.OrderBy` methods.

```
Console.WriteLine(new [] {3, 2, 1}.First());
// here you get 3, not 1.
```

You can see here with a custom `OrderBy` method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var myIEnumerable = GetMyEnumerable();
        foreach(var item in myIEnumerable.MyCustomOrderBy(x => x))
        {           
            if(item == myIEnumerable.First())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The condition is true with: " + item);
            }
        }
    }   

    public static IEnumerable<int> GetMyEnumerable()
    {           
        foreach(var i in new int[] {5, 4, 3, 2, 1})
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetMyEnumerable was called " + i);   
            yield return i;
        }       
    }       
}

public static class OrderByExtensionMethod
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> MyCustomOrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OrderByExtensionMethod was called"); 
        return source.OrderBy(keySelector);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
OrderByExtensionMethod was called
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
GetMyEnumerable was called 4
GetMyEnumerable was called 3
GetMyEnumerable was called 2
GetMyEnumerable was called 1
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
The condition is true with: 5
```

What happened?
Firstly the `MyCustomOrderBy` method is called, he needs to iterate over the entire collection to sort the elements.

```
OrderByExtensionMethod was called
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
GetMyEnumerable was called 4
GetMyEnumerable was called 3
GetMyEnumerable was called 2
GetMyEnumerable was called 1
```

Then your foreach start, and `myIEnumerable.First()` is executed for each item:

```
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
GetMyEnumerable was called 5
```

Finally, you get what you wanted:

```
The condition is true with: 5
```

Comment: You might want to consider changing your `for` loop to `foreach(var item in GetMyEnumerable().OrderBy(x=>x))`, just to better match the question, and show that the `OrderBy` doesn't happen more than once.

Answer (score 0):

for this code:

```
foreach(int iteratorInt in myIEnumerable.OrderBy(x => x.MyProperty))
```

The `OrderBy` is only executed once

Answer (score 0):

The `OrderBy` is evaluated only once, however, a new `IEnumerator<T>` based on the original unordered `myIEnumerable` will be created each iteration, and it will probably not match `iteratorInt` on the first iteration unless the first element just happens to be what would be sorted to the first position.

If you *do* want the first iteration's value of `iteratorInt` to match the enumerable's `First()` result. you would want to create a temporary copy of the ordered enumerable *before the loop*, like this:

```
var list = myIEnumerable.OrderBy(x => x);
foreach(int iteratorInt in list)
{
    if(iteratorInt == list.First())
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Though this is a fairly pointless pattern (similar to the "[Loop-switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence)" anti-pattern), as it can be simplified to:

```
//do something with list.First();
```